# What are the steps to build a bathroom in my basement

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, basement, plumbing-fixture

I want to build 2 bathrooms and a kitchen in my basement

I am trying to do the stuff that I can do by myself and get a prof plumber to help with the stuff that I cannot do.

I also want to prepare by buying goods that I will need in advance (Vanity, Toilet, Shower).

I also have not made my mind yet on if I am going to build the shower (tiles) or get a shower base (which is cheaper and easier to install)

I want to know the steps of doing that so I can prepare.

I am thinking like this (correct me if i am wrong)

1- Rough Plumbing for the shower, toilet and vanity

2- pipes for shower, toilet and vanity on the wall

3- bathroom tiles

4- Shower tiles (or install shower base, bath tub)

5- install shower, toilet and vanity

Comment: What about framing the walls and electric (lights, GFCI outlet)?

Comment: @SteveSh, see i missed some stuff, can you help me with identifying the processes needed in order?

Comment: You can do all of the plumbing yourself. Just not as quickly and you would need some tools. You need to figure out your local regulations. Out here in the Wild West we can do our own plumbing work without having a licensed plumber involved whatsoever in the process. There exist jurisdictions where anything beyond repairing a p-trap below the sink is a misdemeanor.

Comment: Where is the intended location relative to the existing drains? You may need to plan for an ejector pump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot depends on what's already there.

When I did my basement bathroom (with shower), the drain for the shower and the toilet were already there in the floor.

So I first framed the walls (including a doorway), then ran the pipes for the sink, toilet & shower through the studs and stubbed them out.  I also installed shut off valves on the hot and cold water feed coming into the bathroom.

Then I ran the electric, insulated the walls, and installed the shower pan.  That was followed by the drywall and floor (tile over concrete in my case) and the shower surround.  I installed trim as needed, painted everything, and finally installed the vanity and toilet.

I think that's it.  I'll update the answer if more things come up.